# How to run some jUnit (on java-eclipse) projects one by one?

Tags: java, eclipse, batch-file, junit, cmd

I need to rum 3 jUnit projects one by one.
What is the simple way to do it (through cmd/batch/eclipse configuration/external java project)?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Do your projects depend on each other? In which way? How do you deploy your projects?

Comment: It's easy if you use Apache Maven or similar build tools.

Comment: I need to run first project, wait until this project finish its code, then the second project, wait until it ends and then, the third. All of this in one click, but all projects need to run synchronous way and not together.

Comment: how can i do it through apache maven

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do it (unless you need it in one click) is to right-click on the project and use "Run As> JUnit Test" for each project. After you run it once, it will be "cached" in the "Run" button in the   upper control bar or in the JUnit view "History".

If you need to run all 3 in 1 click, then you are better off with Maven, Ant or something similar that has a good integration with Eclipse.

Comment: Hi shlomi,I need to run first project, wait until this project finish its code, then the second project, wait until it ends and then, the third. All of this in one click, but all projects need to run synchronous way and not together.

Comment: You can use Maven to do this for you. If you are not into Maven I think that the only way is as you've suggested: as an external tool configuration. If you have trouble finding the right command I can try and help you. Just know that making your project a Maven project is the best solution!

Comment: Hi,I have 3 maven projects. On each project I have a class which extends SystemTestCase4 and run a specific Before, Test and After.Every project have a different SUT folder. I want to create an outer project which run project#1, and then project#2 and then project#3.

Comment: Great! I suggest you post that as a different question in stackoverflow as this is an issue of itself

Comment: I found a great solution.

Comment: install usus project from marketplace. Then you can run some projects one by one: put your cursor on descendant project and make sure this maven project hold all required dependencies. then you can run some projects via run conf